# Synching two different USB drives not connected simultaneously

Tags: usb, software-rec, external-hard-drive, sync, storage

I'm trying to find a software that can handle my requirement. I have a notebook that I use at work and Home. I have an external usb drive here at work and another one at home. I would like to find a software that synchronize those two drives.

This thing should be done in different ways but what I expect should be the behavior is something like:

I get to work and use the external HD. Meanwhile in the notebook (or remotely via a NAS or FTP server) it tracks down every file I added or modified or deleted. When I get home and connect to the other drive the software should recognize the drive and sync it with the info the notebook collected. Then it starts collecting infos on the change I make on the Home HD that will be synched to the Work HD whenever I reconnect to it.

Is there some kind of software that can do something like that? Any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

[Unison](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/wiki/index.php) should be able to do this.  The FAQ article on syncing two systems using a removable drive should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your operating system, but something wrapped around or along the lines of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) can probably get you close to where you want to be.  How to invoke rsync when you mount your drive would be very OS dependent, but I believe it can be done for most modern OSes.

Comment: Sorry, my OS is Win7. I will try to take a look at Unison and ask their group if it can do what I need. Othwerwise I will look for rsync. Thanks!